# Looping Through Multidimensional Array to iterate each item in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

how can I do Looping Through to iterate each item console.log, 
**I want to iterate only for a loop way** 
this is the array

```
let array = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [[10,11,12],13,14],
    [[15,16,16],[17,18,[19,20]]]
];
```

Comment: How your are trying to Iterate it.? Its better to show what you achieved and where you stuck.

Comment: let array = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [[10,11,12],13,14],
    [[15,16,16],[17,18,[19,20]]]
]
for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    for(let j=0; j<array[i].length; j++){
        console.log(array[i][j])
    }
}

output this 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
[ 10, 11, 12 ]
13
14
[ 15, 16, 16 ]
[ 17, 18, [ 19, 20 ] ]

Answer (score 0):

You would need a nested loop. JavaScript has different ways to do this. Here's an example following Functional Programming:

```
array.forEach(function (outer) {
    outer.forEach(function (inner) {
        console.log(inner)
    })
});
```

Since you have a deeply nested array, you might also want to [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) it first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this?

This function should console log every item in the array **and** all sub-arrays.

```js
// using Array.forEach
const recursiveLoop1 = (elem) => {
  if (Array.isArray(elem)) {
    elem.forEach((innerElem) => {
      recursiveLoop1(innerElem)
    })
  } else {
    console.log(elem)
  }
}

// using classic for-loop
const recursiveLoop2 = (elem) => {
  if (Array.isArray(elem)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
      recursiveLoop2(elem[i])
    }
  } else {
    console.log(elem)
  }
}

let array = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9],
  [[10,11,12],13,14],
  [[15,16,16],[17,18,[19,20]]]
];

recursiveLoop1(array);
recursiveLoop2(array);
```

Comment: I need to for looping through to iterating is  each item

Comment: @Robiul I updated the answer with a recursive function that uses a standard for-loop, is that helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Get a flat array and iterate for an ouput.

```js
let array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [[10, 11, 12], 13, 14], [[15, 16, 16], [17, 18, [19, 20]]]];

array
    .flat(Infinity)
    .forEach(v => console.log(v));
```

A more classic approach with a recursive callback.

```js
const show = v => {
        if (Array.isArray(v)) v.forEach(show);
        else console.log(v);
    };

let array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [[10, 11, 12], 13, 14], [[15, 16, 16], [17, 18, [19, 20]]]];

array.forEach(show);
```

Comment: I need to for looping way to iterate all things